# How to get the word count for all the documents based on index and type in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have few documents and would like to get the count of each word in all the documents for a particular field how do I get?

ex: Doc1 : *"aaa bbb aaa ccc"*
    doc2 : *"aaa ccc"*
    doc3 : *"www"*

I want it like **aaa-3, bbb-1, ccc-2, www-1**

Answer (score 3):

If you want the document counts, you can do it by using a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) like this:

```
POST your_index/_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "counts" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "your_field" }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to get the term count, you need to use the [`_termvector` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html), however, you'll only be able to query one document after another.

```
GET /your_index/your_type/1/_termvector?fields=your_field
```

And for doc1 you'll get

- aaa: 2
- bbb: 1
- ccc: 1

The [multi-term vectors API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-termvectors.html) can help but you'll still need to specify the documents to get the term vectors from.

```
POST /your_index/your_type/_mtermvectors' -d '{
   "docs": [
      {
         "_id": "1"
      },
      {
         "_id": "2"
      },
      {
         "_id": "3"
      }
   ]
}'
```

And for your docs you'll get

- aaa: 2 + 1
- bbb: 1
- ccc: 1 + 1
- www: 1

Comment: A terms aggregation only returns the document count for each term. This is the amount of documents that are pointed to for each term in the inverted index (and even only approximately when running in a clustered mode). So in this case, you would only get aaa-2 bbb-1 ccc-2 www-1. The information about the two occurences of aaa in document 1 is lost. For details see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Comment: Good point @AndreasJägle, I've misread the question, my bad. I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: thank you @Val for answering but I want the count of each word in all documents without providing IDs. I dont want the word count. Is there any way that would help me in achieving this?

Comment: @MahalakshmiRamanathan have you found a solution?